# Trigger on Tab Control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tabcontrol

I Had a Tabcontrol 
and a RichTextBox control as below

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TabItem Header="Edit" TabIndex="0" />
        <TabItem Header="View" TabIndex="1" />
</TabControl>

<RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox"> </RichTextBox>
```

and now I have two Styles defined like

```
<Style TargetType="Table" x:Key="EditStyleKey">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Table" x:Key="ViewStyleKey">
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

I will create a table in Rich text box.

My problem is that when I select the first tabitem (SelectedIndex=0) then I should apply trigger to change the style "EditKeyStyle" for table in richtextbox. and when I select the second tab (SelectedIndex=1) then I should apply the "ViewStyleKey" for Richtextbox.

As I am new to WPF I couldn't able to fix it using the trigger and I am not sure of where to write the trigger for these kind of dependency.

Someone please provide me help for fixing this issue as this is a high priority issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a single Style with Style.Triggers and DataTriggers to control the style of the table in your RichTextBox. The code below changes the BroderThickness and Padding properties based on the value of the SelectedIndex you'll have to change the SelectedIndex binding so that it points to your TabControl.SelectedIndex property.

I've used something similar to the code below in a project

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="tableStyleKey" TargetType="Table" >
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<RichTextBox>
       <Table Style="{StaticResource tableStyleKey}"/>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Hi Kristian , Thanks for your response. Here I had a problem, That is I will create table and tablecell dynamically. So I should apply styles to table and tablecell based on tabItem Seleceted. So I couldn't apply this style '<Table Style="{StaticResource tableStyleKey}"/>' directly in  richtextbox.Could you please provide me some other solution.

Comment: @user2337613 You can use a `ContentControl` instead of a `Table`, and swap out the `ContentTemplate` in your DataTrigger. Kristian is right thought, the best solution for changing a property based on a bound value is a `DataTrigger`

Comment: Based on you inputs here is the code   '<RichTextBox>
   <RichTextBox.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="TableCell" >
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding ="{Binding Path=TabIndex}" Value="0">
              <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding ="{Binding Path=TabIndex}" Value="1">
              <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
          </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
   </RichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>'